# Marginal probability density of x (obs) obtained by integrating x(missing)

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, missing-data, numerical-integration

I am reading a text book on missing data, and a sentence below is slightly challenging for me to understand.

> The marginal probability density of $ \left ( x_{obs}\ \right)$ is obtained by integrating the missing data $ \left ( x_{miss}\ \right)$ 
>   $$ f\left ( x_{obs}|\theta \right )=\int_{}^{}f\left ( x_{obs},x_{miss} \right ){}dx_{miss}\\\\{}$$

I need help understanding this, with an example preferably.

Comment: There is nothing to understand. Please explain better what is your problem. Maybe this will help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_probability

Comment: I understand marginal pdf I want to know how this is applied in a missing data situation with an example

Comment: The formula should be $$ f\left ( x_{obs}|\theta \right )=\int_{}^{}f\left ( x_{obs},x_{miss}| \theta \right ){}dx_{miss}\\\\{}$$ otherwise doesn't make sense. If you can be more specific i will try to help, otherwise i really do not understand what is your problem

Comment: Let us assume I have 3 variables x1, x2, x3 all three have missing data x1 { 20 obs 10 miss } x2 { 15 obs 15 miss } x3 { 8 obs 22 miss } , how does this apply to this example ?

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase it would be "integrate *over* the missing data" or "integrate *out* the likelihood of the missing data."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a notation problem. Let us assume to have 3 variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and let $x_{1,miss}$, $x_{2,miss}$ and $x_{3,miss}$ be the vector of missing values of respectively $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_{1,obs}$, $x_{2,obs}$ and $x_{3,obs}$ be the vector of missing values of respectively $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$.

If you want to calculate the marginal density, conditioning to the vector $\theta$ is

$$
f(x_{1,obs},x_{2,obs},x_{3,obs}|\theta) =
$$
$$
 =\int_{x_{1,miss}, x_{2,miss},x_{3,miss}} f(x_{1,obs},x_{2,obs},x_{3,obs},x_{1,miss},x_{2,miss},x_{3,miss}|\theta) d x_{1,miss}, dx_{2,miss}dx_{3,miss}
$$

Comment: A notational problem still remains: your description suggests that the $x_{i,miss}$ are vectors of *numbers*, in which case the integral makes no sense. If they are to be considered random vectors, we can make sense of the integral by assuming you mean "$dx_{i,miss}$" to refer to the distributions of those vectors, but this is still an abuse of notation and it is ambiguous, because some sense of a *joint* distribution is needed. Evidently that comes from a context and additional assumptions adopted implicitly both by you and the OP. Could you state those assumptions and clarify the notation?

Comment: I was just using the same notation used by bison2178, if for example  in the original question, $x_{miss} = (x_{1,miss},x_{2,miss}, \dots , x_{n,miss})$, the integral $$\int_{x_{miss}}f(x_{obs}, x_{miss}| \theta) d x_{miss}  $$ should be read as $$ \int_{x_{1,miss}}\int_{x_{2,miss}} \dots \int_{x_{n,miss}} f(x_{obs}, x_{miss}| \theta) d x_{n,miss}, \dots , d x_{2,miss} d x_{1,miss} $$